# How to upload Stripe identity_document from S3 url with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I need to send an identity document to Stripe with `stripe-ruby` directly from an S3 URL like that:

```
picture_s3_url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/foo.png"

file = File.new(open(picture_s3_url))

token = Stripe::FileUpload.create(
    {
        purpose: "identity_document",
        file: file
    },
    {
        stripe_account: stripe_account_id
    }
)
```

And if it's possible, without creating a local file.

How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `File.new` seems a bit odd. You should take advantage of [`IO.binwrite`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.4/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) instead:

```
IO.binwrite('img.jpg', open('https://picsum.photos/200').string)

token = Stripe::FileUpload.create(
    {
        purpose: "identity_document",
        file: File.new('img.jpg')
    },
    {
        stripe_account: stripe_account_id
    }
)
```

Optionnally you could use [`Tempfile`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) to ensure a unique filename.